# How do I set the base source path for Jython code embedded into a Java project?

Tags: jython

I'm using Jython code embedded into a Java project. I can import Jython packages from Java just fine if they are in the standard output folder of the Java project (bin/ during development or in the root inside the JAR) like this:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.exec("import pypkg");
```

However, I'd like to store them under py/ in the JAR. When I do that, I get a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pypkg
```

How do I tell `PythonInterpreter` which base path to look for .py files inside the JAR?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an `__init__.py` file in the py directory, that is most likely the problem. I just tried importing a single `.py` file from a `.jar` file in a directory one level down from the root and it worked. I was using Jython 2.5.2.

Comment: I do have `__init__.py` files in all my packages, of course. If it worked for you, how did you go about telling Jython to look in your `py/` directory?